# Quartz simple trigger not working after sometime

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz simple trigger (quartz 2.2.1) with setting as repeat indefinitely. All schedules were running fine in production but recently they stopped working and also the next fire time is not updating.
If I update the schedule using rescheduleJob quartz API, it works fine for sometime and then again goes in stuck state.
Any info on as to how this is happening?

Thread dump shows all threads in Timed waiting state with onObject monitoring.

```
"UDPQuartzScheduler_Worker-8" #49 prio=4 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f88d71a8000 nid=0x30b6 in Object.wait() [0x00007f8928b30000]
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
    - locked <0x00000006ddc9d6b0> (a java.lang.Object)

"UDPQuartzScheduler_Worker-7" #48 prio=4 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f88d71a6000 nid=0x30b5 in Object.wait() [0x00007f8928c31000]
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
    - locked <0x00000006ddc9d6f8> (a java.lang.Object)

"UDPQuartzScheduler_Worker-6" #47 prio=4 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f88d71a4000 nid=0x30b4 in Object.wait() [0x00007f8928d32000]
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
    - locked <0x00000006ddc9f000> (a java.lang.Object)
```

Comment: You need to dig deeper. Is the last execution finished properly? Did it take longer to execute, than the repeat interval? I'd focus on the last execution to see if it holds any answers, debugging and logging should give you more data on why the execution is skipped.

Comment: @PredragMaric Hey, so what happened was the application db (mysql) was down for sometime so quartz was unable to connect to the db. The thing thats bugging me is that even though the db went up and I restarted the application, why is quartz not picking up the scheduled jobs at all.

Comment: Exactly the same problem we had on one project (just on Oracle). Never got to the bottom of the problem, but our conclusion was that Quartz simply needs to restart also when DB is restarted. We had a lot of strange symptoms, besides simply skipping the execution (multiple executions of the same job, etc)

Comment: @PredragMaric You may want to turn that conclusion into an answer.

Comment: @PredragMaric I tested this hypothesis, stopped mysql service and started it again after 10 minutes (meanwhile checking the application logs the entire time).
Was getting error like : org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'springNonTxDataSource.schedulerFactoryBean': com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

But as I started mysql, quartz was able to start the next trigger without application needing restart.

Comment: @Karshit Did it continue to work properly? Maybe there are some other conditions involved that lead to strange behavior.

Comment: @walen Thanks, but I would also like to see a proper answer to this question. Mine was more or less just about confirming the problem.

Comment: @PredragMaric Then upvoting the question might help a bit :) just did so myself. Also bear in mind that your comment is _an_ answer (even if it's not _the_ answer to Karshit's problem) and it might help other users looking for help with the same error, users which probably won't even bother to read this question if it has 0 answers. It will get users' attention and hopefully a proper answer.

Comment: @walen Good point, thanks. I've upvoted the question and added the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You might face same issue even after increasing thread count because your worker threads will get stuck again. 
To resolve this issue, you have to review your worker thread code and **check weather they are getting stuck** or **where some task taking too much execution time** ( basically its happen when you write/read too much data ).  This two reasons also creates misfire issue.

if you could not find any thing related to the points i mentioned above then you could create **separate thread through worker instead of executing it on worker thread**. it will definitely solve your problem but if you have too many threads stuck in application process, then your application will get stuck but as same time you'll get exact reason for this issue from application process stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same problem we had on one project (just on Oracle). Never got to the bottom of the problem, but our conclusion was that Quartz also needs to be restarted when DB is restarted.

We had a lot of strange symptoms, besides simply skipping the execution - multiple executions of the same job, workers not synced in the cluster setup, etc. All of this was random, and we couldn't identify any patterns.

Comment: In checked with multiple applications, server start was not required and quartz automatically picked up the next run when DB was up.
In my case, I was using only 8 threads and now I have increased it to 20. haven't faced the issue in that application for now.
Any idea on how to enable logging on quartz.

Comment: @Karshit Logging should be documented, can't remember the details. We had a clustered quartz installation, maybe that's what was causing the issue